# How to normalize data before evaluation in scikit-multiflow?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a CSV file that has 9 features and 9 expected targets, and I want to test 2 regression models on this data (that should be generated as a stream).

When I test 2 models with the same data (generated as a stream using **scikit-multiflow** from the CSV file) I get a bad R2_score.

But when I test it with a normalized version of my data using scikit-learn I get a very good R2 score. The problem is that I should not use scikit-learn because I should be normalizing data in real-time.

So I searched for something like that in scikit-multiflow and I found 2 methods: `normalize_sample(X)`, `and normalize_targets(y)`.

But the problem is that normalize_sample depends on a variable called examples_seen, this variable is the number of examples that the model has already used (for training, and testing). 
As far as I know, this variable changes when we call the "evaluate" method on a model.
But this doesn't make any sense, because we should normalize data and then train it and not the opposite. I'm sure I'm missing something here. 
Can anyone help me please because there is no example of this kind of use.

```
    import csv
    from skmultiflow.data.file_stream import FileStream
    from skmultiflow.trees import MultiTargetRegressionHoeffdingTree
    from skmultiflow.evaluation import EvaluatePrequential
    from skmultiflow.meta import RegressorChain
    stream = FileStream('supervised_file_v4.csv', target_idx=9, n_targets=9)
    stream.prepare_for_use()
    ht = MultiTargetRegressionHoeffdingTree()
    rh = RegressorChain()
    ht.normalize_sample(stream.X)
    # here it gives me an array of 10 zeros beacause examples_seen = 0
    evaluator = EvaluatePrequential(show_plot=False,
                            pretrain_size=30000,
                            max_samples=200000, 
                           metrics = ['average_mean_absolute_error','average_root_mean_square_error'])
    # print(ht.examples_seen) gives 0
    evaluator.evaluate(stream=stream, model=[ht,rh], model_names=['HT', 'RH'])
    # print(ht.examples_seen) gives 200000
    ht.normalize_sample(stream.X)
    # even here it gives a error saying "operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5733524,9) (9,) (5733524,) (9,)"
```

I expect there is a way we can use "`normalize_sample`" before calling the "`evaluate`" method. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In short:** The current version of `scikit-multiflow` (0.3.0) does not provide a dedicated method to normalize data incrementally. This is only performed internally by some regression models (`RegressionHoeffdingTree` and `MultiTargetRegressionHoeffdingTree`).

**About the implementation details:**
The normalized data from `sklearn` is different given that, as you mention, it takes into consideration all the data. On the other hand, `normalize_sample` and `normalize_targets` perform the normalization incrementally, as new samples are observed *by the model*.

The  `evaluate` method is not part of the model but of the evaluator class (`EvaluatePrequential` in your example). In particular, the prequential evaluator first calls the `predict` (test) method and then the `partial_fit` method of the corresponding model(s). The internal parameter `samples_seen` is **only** updated during training.

**Source:** I am the maintainer of `scikit-multiflow`

**Note:** A fast way to reach the developers and the community of `scikit-multiflow` is via the official platforms (user-group, chat, GitHub page).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, you said there are some regression models that can perform data normalization incrementally, can you please give me some names (even if they're single-target models)? Can you suggest me something else (to normalize data) ?

Comment: I have edited my answer to mention the algorithms that perform normalization internally. An alternative is the creation of a `normalize` transformer to be paired with a model.

Comment: Thank you so much, regarding the transformer do you mean something like in this link https://scikit-multiflow.github.io/scikit-multiflow/_autosummary/skmultiflow.core.Pipeline.html?highlight=transformer

Comment: Yes. In the example, a `transformer` object (`one_hot_to_categorical`) is paired with a model. This is handled by the `pipeline` object.